# Calculating a sample size

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation, parameter-estimation

I can't figure out how to crack this problem. It's as if I don't have enough information. Walk me through please

> Jogging is a popular sport in Brilliantia. According to a recent survey, between 80% and 84% of Brillantians jog at least once a week. This conclusion was reached with 90% confidence.
>
> How many Brilliantians were in the surveyed random sample?

The $z$-score for $90\%$ confidence is $1.645$ and the standard error estimate for a sample proportion with size $n$ is
$$
SE = \sqrt{\frac{\hat{p} (1-\hat{p})}{n}}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you got to the right place:
$$
\begin{split}
\hat{p} &- 1.645 E\ &= 0.8\\
\hat{p} &+ 1.645 E\ &= 0.84
\end{split}
$$
Now add the equations to get the value of $\hat{p}$ (which you could also get from the symmetry of the confidence interval) and then solve for $E$.

Comment: Thank you for the swift response